# tensorflow print out L2 norm

Tags: tensorflow, norm

I am new to tensorflow and hope you can help me.

I would like print out the l2 difference between two vectors (x[0]- y[0]) *  (x[0]- y[0])  + (x[1]- y[1]) *  (x[1]- y[1]) + ...

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf;

sess=tf.InteractiveSession()

xx = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]];
yy = [[2.0, 3.0, 4.0]];
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 3], name='x')   
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 3], name='y') 
cost = tf.nn.l2_loss(x - y, name='cost')

sess.run([cost, y], feed_dict={x: xx, y:yy})
print(cost, y);

But here is the output 

Tensor("cost:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) Tensor("y:0", shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32).
```

How can I print out the actually value?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the returned values from `sess.run`:

```py
cost_, y_ = sess.run([cost, y], feed_dict={x: xx, y:yy})
print(cost_, y_);

# 1.5 [[ 2.  3.  4.]]
```